# Not able to send mail on server. Getting exception The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

Guys I have a class where I am sending mail to all the students in database.When I send mails on my local host mails get send easily but when I upload my code to the server. I am getting this exception :

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure
>   connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response
>   was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at at
>   System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode,
>   String response) at System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.Send(SmtpConnection
>   conn, Byte[] command, MailAddress from, Boolean allowUnicode) at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender,
>   MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, Boolean
>   allowUnicode, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception) at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) at
>   HotelWeb.SMTPHelper.SendEmail(String From, String FromDisplayName,
>   String To, String Cc, String Bcc, String Subject, String Body, Boolean
>   SendMailInBackGround) in
>   e:\hostingspaces\ubi9009\ihmsgr.taqwatechnologies.net\wwwroot\App_Code\SMTPHelper.cs:line
>   140 at HotelWeb.MAILnSMS.sendBulkMail() in e:\

hostingspaces\ubi9009\ihmsgr.taqwatechnologies.net\wwwroot\App_Code\MAILnSMS.cs:line 95

My code works fine on local machine but doestnt work on server is like this :

public static void sendBulkMail()
        {

```
        _ds = new DataSet();



        SMTPBAL smtpbl = new SMTPBAL(0);
        smtpbl.LoadAll(_ds);

        string server = _ds.Tables[smtpbl.SqlEntityX].Rows[0]["SMTPX"].ToString();
        int smtpPort = WebHelper.Cast(_ds.Tables[smtpbl.SqlEntityX].Rows[0]["smtpPort"].ToString(), 0);
        string From = _ds.Tables[smtpbl.SqlEntityX].Rows[0]["Email"].ToString();
        string User = _ds.Tables[smtpbl.SqlEntityX].Rows[0]["User"].ToString();
        string Password = _ds.Tables[smtpbl.SqlEntityX].Rows[0]["Password"].ToString();
        string sDisclaimer = _ds.Tables[smtpbl.SqlEntityX].Rows[0]["Disclaimer"].ToString();
        bool EnableSSl = WebHelper.Cast(_ds.Tables[smtpbl.SqlEntityX].Rows[0]["EnableSll"], false);
        string EmailAddress = string.Empty;

        StudentBAL _stbl = new StudentBAL(0);
        _stbl.LoadAll(_ds);

        foreach (DataRow dr in _ds.Tables[_stbl.SqlEntityX].Rows)
        {
            try
            {
                if (dr["Email"] != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    if (IsValidMailAddress(dr["Email"].ToString()))
                    {
                        string Message = "Dear parent,<br/><br/> <br/> The Attendance for current course/semester of your ward," + dr["Name"].ToString() + " is available on the given below link.Please check and contact HOD in case any enquiry.<br/><br/><br/>Copy below link to your browsers address bar. <br/><br/>http://ihmsgr.taqwatechnologies.net/login/login.aspx <br/>User Name :" + dr["LoginEmailAddress"].ToString() + " / " + dr["EmailAddress"].ToString() + "<br/>Password : " + dr["Password"].ToString() + "<br/><br/><br/>Regard's<br/><br/>Institute of hotel management.<br/>Srinagar.";


                        SMTPHelper SMTP1 = new SMTPHelper(server, smtpPort, From, Password, EnableSSl, true);
                        SMTP1.IsHTML = true;

                        SMTP1.SendEmail(From, "Institute of hotel management", dr["Email"].ToString(), "", "", "Attendance status of your ward.", Message, false);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err) {


            }

        }

    }
```

I am using hosting space on Server http://www.arvixe.com/ PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 1):

**That error message is typically caused by one of the following:**

- Incorrect connection settings, such as the wrong port specified for
  the secured or non-secured connection
- Incorrect credentials. Please verify the username and password
  combination, to make sure the credentials are correct.

Also, if it still does not work, then try setting `DeliveryMethod` of SmtpClient as `SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network`

**Following is the code snippet for the same**

```
var smtp = new SmtpClient
           {
               Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
               Port = 587,
               EnableSsl = true,
               DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
               UseDefaultCredentials = false,
               Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
           };
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use smtp account associated with your website domain to send email from website. Make sure that you use correct server and credentials as described at http://blog.arvixe.com/how-do-i-authenticate-emails-in-asp-net-using-smtp/ Also there is a support forum at http://forum.arvixe.com/smf/community-applications/asp-net-smtp-demo/ where you could ask for further help regarding your host.

Comment: I need to send mail using smtp setting of other server. can i do this please help

Comment: I'd suggest to make a test page where you can set all values in plain text, deploy it to the server and see if it works. Currently it is not clear what values you do have (e.g. what is value for the port, smtp, etc). Also read this http://forum.arvixe.com/smf/tutorials/sending-email-from-net-issue-again!/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. There is a section which defines credentials. Use windows NTid and not email address

```
Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "pwd"), // email id would be username@domain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Goto your Google account setting then security section and search for "Less secure app access". Turn on this option and it should work.